# Crossdomain в XMLSocket

Tags: flash, java

Здравствуйте!
При написании Flash агента с XMLSocket (сервер JAVA) столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Когда клиент заходит на сайт подгружается Flash ролик и устанавливается соединение с XMLSocket, дело в том что Flash ролик автоматически реконнектится при пропаже соединения и выходит вот что:

1. Клиент зашёл ролик соединился с
       сервером по XMLSocket
2. Ролик запрашивает <policy-file-request/>
       (Я такого не задавал судя по всему
       это flash с его безопасностью)
3. При любом ответе сервера (я даже
       сделал чтобы сервер при таком
       запросе отвечал
       <cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from
       domain="*" to-ports="*"
       meta-policy="master-only"
       /></cross-domain-policy> соединение
       закрывается.
4. Ролик возобновляет
       соединение снова и больше соединение
       не пропадает и этого странного
       запроса больше нету

Исходник JAVA сейчас:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            if (configurate()) {
                Integer b = 0;
                ServerSocket a = new ServerSocket(8572);
                ...
                while(true) {
                    new ur(b++, a.accept());
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
public ur(Integer a, Socket b) throws IOException {
    cb = a;
    ca = b;
        ...
        setDaemon(true);
        setPriority(NORM_PRIORITY);
        start();
}
public void run() {
    try {
    while(true){
    InputStream cg = ca.getInputStream();
            String a = new String(cc, 0, cg.read(cc), "UTF-8").trim();

            System.out.println(a);
            if (a != null){
                if (! a.equals("<policy-file-request/>")) {
                    ...
                } else {
                    write("<cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"*\" meta-policy=\"master-only\" /></cross-domain-policy>");
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            ca.close(); // Требуется для закрытия сокета если клиент закрыл страницу в браузере, пробывал это убрать всё абсолютно так же

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    } 
}
```

Если тот же самый агент я делаю в AIR и использую там никаких странных запросов не идёт и всё коннектится с 1 раза, кто может подсказать в чём проблема?

Comment: Не JAVA, а Java! - в следующий раз буду минусовать!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все правильно, политика безопасности флеш плеера, если домен сервера не совпадает с доменом расположения самого ролика.

В AIR такого нет, это обычные приложения, с широкими полномочиями.

Подробней [тут](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c60.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c63).

Comment: Но XMLScoket то по IP, или если расположить их на 1 сервере этого не будет?
Если выполнить требования по указанной вами ссылке этого не будет? Или это неотемлимая часть XMLSocket-ов?

Comment: Там вся сеть по IP.

Не будет.